# Inserting a caption into the Twitter 'tweet' or Facebook 'like' for Fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, fancybox

When I click an image and click on the Twitter or Facebook share buttons, it shares the title of the page with a link to the photo. Is there a way I can insert the title of the image in there? Fancybox grabs the `title` attribute of the image (i.e. "1st title", "2nd title") but I don't know how to get that into the actual tweet. I couldn't find any information about that in the [Fancybox docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3

HTML

```
<a title="1st title" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a title="2nd title" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

JS

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
                // New line
                this.title += '<br />';

                // Add tweet button
                this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

                // Add FaceBook like button
                this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
            }
        },
        afterShow: function() {
            // Render tweet button
            twttr.widgets.load();
        },
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is half of the answer.

For twitter you may need to capture in a variable the original `title` before adding any social media buttons. Then use twitter's `data-text` attribute to set that value like :

```
beforeShow: function () {
    if (this.title) {

        var _title = this.title; // capture original title

        // New line
        this.title += '<br />';

        // Add tweet button WITH data-text parameter
        this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-text="' + _title + '" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

        // Add FaceBook like button
        this.title += '{facebook iframe}';
    }
},
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pcvqovve/)**

**NOTE** : I am not sure Facebook allows you to pass that information (that would be the other half of the answer)

Comment: Badabing badabang! Thank you. For the Facebook button, I decided to just add the 'share' button by adding `&amp;share=true` to the parameters.